# Why did the Sensates need to be "awoken" to sense each-other?

Tags: sense8

In the show *Sense8*, an event in the 1st episode triggers each of the 8 characters to begin sensing each-other. However in later episodes it is explained that

> Each of the 8 are born and take their first breath together; they are connected at the moment of birth.

At the point of the show they are in their late 20's. If

> they have been linked since birth

why only now are they able to sense each-other?

Answer (score 4):

The very first scene between Jonas and Angelica seems to imply that it was Angelica that first opened the connection between them all. She was the catalyst that was able to reach out and connect them. Without that, it's possible their abilities would never have been triggered at all.

Further, the conversation between Riley and Grace gives the impression that

> Jonas and Angelica at one point worked for BPO awakening sensates specifically so they could be tracked down and neutralized.

So it would appear that some sensates have the ability to cross-pollinate, as it were, and jump start dormant clusters.

Comment: Sorry for all the hedging language, but with what little we have so far, this is really speculative until we get more concrete canon explanations.

Comment: Yeah, it seems like most questions about sense 8 right now are pretty speculative. That's not a bad answer. My only counter-point would be how do we explain Wil's situation as a child? It seems like his abilities would have been active since childhood if not at birth.

Comment: My guess is that he only "visited" with Sara and never "shared" with her, by the way he talked about it. (I don't recall if he knew Sara before she went missing and therefore could have made eye contact.) In which case, the two were probably members of different clusters.

Comment: The two of them would have definitely been in different clusters given the rules we do know. But if all it takes to awaken a sense8's abilities is to connect with another sense8 regardless of cluster, then Wil's abilities would have been awakened as a child... Though, I guess there is the point where since the rest of his cluster is still dormant, he wouldn't really be able to use his abilities.